# Erro ao abrir o editor de texto no Git

Tags: git, editor-de-texto, atom

Estou tentando trocar a mensagem do meu último *commit* através do Git Bash utilizando o comando `git commit --amend`. Porém, quando ele tenta abrir o editor, o Git gera o seguinte erro:

```
$ git commit --amend
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 'C:\Users\Jean' não é reconhecido 
como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

[main 47981f3] added day-10 challenge part 2
 Date: Mon Dec 14 20:49:23 2020 -0200
 3 files changed, 145 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
 create mode 100644 2020/day-10/input.txt
 create mode 100644 2020/day-10/solution.py
```

O meu editor é o Atom e eu configurei ele para o Git da seguinte forma:

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Como eu posso corrigir esse problema?

Comment: Já consultou `git config --list` pra garantir que está configurado como você deseja? Talvez você tenha espaços no seu nome de usuário?

Comment: Parece que é um problema específico no Atom do Windows. Veja [aqui](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/16740) e [aqui](https://discuss.atom.io/t/problem-using-atom-1-32-2-as-git-commit-editor/60550/6). E [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218086/git-commit-command-is-not-working-properly-with-atom-editor) também.

Comment: @Hildeberto sim, está configurado e sim, eu há um espaçamento no nome de usuário

Answer (score 0):

Tenta rodar o comando abaixo novamente mas colocando aspas simples em vez de aspas duplas:

```
git config --global core.editor 'atom --wait'
```